# Trying to set an increment controller

Tags: javascript, increment, ecmascript-5

I'm building a simple trivia app and so far its great, but I have a problem with proceeding to the next question.
oddly enough when the user Answer correctly to the question and presses the submit button it does increment to the next question but if they answer correctly again it does nothing.

Here is my code:

```
  <div class="app">
      <h2 id="question"></h2>
          <button class="options" type="button" value="val"></button>
          <button class="options" type="button" value="val"></button>
          <button class="options" type="button" value="val"></button>
          <button class="options" type="button" value="val"></button>
        </br>
            <button id="submit" type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
            <button id="back" type="button" name="button">Back</button>
    </div>



var data = {
  currentQuestion: 0,
  questions:[
    {
      answers:[1,3,5,6],
      question:'how much is 3+3',
      correctAnswer:6
     },
    {
      answers:[1,3,5,2],
      question:'how much is 1+1',
      currectAnswer:2
    },
     {
       answers:[1,8,5,6],
       question:'how much is 4+4',
       correctAnswer:8
     },
     {
       answers:[1,8,10,6],
       question:'how much is 4+6',
       correctAnswer:8
     }
  ]
}


var options = document.querySelectorAll('.options');
var question = document.querySelector('#question');
var backBtn = document.querySelector('#back');
var submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submit');





function init() {
  newQuestion();
  optionClick();
  evaluate();
  back();

}


function newQuestion() {
  question.textContent = data.questions[data.currentQuestion].question;
  for(var i = 0; i< data.questions.length; i++) {
    options[i].textContent = data.questions[data.currentQuestion].answers[i]
  }
}



function optionClick() {
    options.forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.classList.toggle('picked')
      })
    })

}


function evaluate() {
  submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for(i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      if(options[i].classList.contains('picked') && options[i].textContent == data.questions[data.currentQuestion].correctAnswer && data.currentQuestion <= 6){
        options[i].classList.remove('picked')
        data.currentQuestion++
        newQuestion();
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Also, I currently running 4 buttons which represents the 4 options out of the possible answers and they all share the same class and I select them as querySelectorAll to define them as an array.
also I've created a simple "picked" class in my css to light up the selected answer's border.
My question if there is a way to limit the toggle class option to have only 1 element at a time and so if I click on another option then the previous option that was selected will be toggled off.
ty in advance(-:

Comment: You left out the part where you attach the events, that could be important to helping you figure it out. Is `optionClick` only run in `init` or is it run when an option is clicked? The way it is now, every time `optionClick` runs, it reattaches a new event to each button. Likewise, every time `evaluate` runs, it attaches a new event handler to `submitBtn`. Generally with this kind of stuff you want to just attach the event once at the beginning. Also, the actual HTML structure (of the relevant elements) could be helpful. [mcve]

Comment: Ty I added the HTML.
The optionClick event is set in the init because they way this app looks is that u have the question and under that u have 4 square buttons so that when u choose 1 of the buttons(answer option) u then submit it with the "submit" button below and then the evaluation happens.

Comment: If you're observing the issue only after the "how much is 1+1" question, it could be because that object does not have a "correctAnswer" property. Instead, it has a "currectAnswer" property, which could be causing the issue.

Comment: I wanted to separate this optionClick event function to make it modular

Comment: wow thank u, darn amazing how a small type mistake can mess up everything (-:
wow, u have an eye of a hawk!!!

Comment: Another thing, you [didn't declare the](http://www.uselesscode.org/blog/posts/always-declare-your-variables-in-javascript/) `i` variable in the loop inside `evaluate`, making it an implicit global, which could cause problems down the line.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been answered in the comments, the problem was a typo, `currectAnswer` rather than `correctAnswer`. It's kind of moot answering now, but I also wanted to suggest some other improvements.

The first thing I would do is instead of using a group of buttons, use a group of radio buttons. You can style them to look like a button if you want, plus you get free functionality by doing that. Radio buttons enforce only having one answer selected without any need to check for multiple answers in code.

Instead of using named functions that when called attach an anonymous function as an event handler, just create a named function and then attach them directly to the elements.

Pulling it together it would look something like this:

```js
'use strict';
var data = {
  currentQuestion: 0,
  questions:[
    {
      answers:[1,3,5,6],
      question:'how much is 3+3',
      correctAnswer:6
     },
    {
      answers:[1,3,5,2],
      question:'how much is 1+1',
      correctAnswer:2
    },
     {
       answers:[1,8,5,6],
       question:'how much is 4+4',
       correctAnswer:8
     },
     {
       answers:[1,8,10,6],
       question:'how much is 4+6',
       correctAnswer:10
     }
  ]
}


var options = document.querySelectorAll('#options input');
var question = document.querySelector('#question');
var backBtn = document.querySelector('#back');
var submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submit');

function nextQuestion () {
  if (data.currentQuestion < data.questions.length - 1) {
    data.currentQuestion += 1;
    displayQuestion();
  } else {
    data.currentQuestion = data.questions.length;
    submitBtn.removeEventListener('click', evaluate);
    backBtn.removeEventListener('click', prevQuestion);
    question.textContent = "Done!"
  }
}

function prevQuestion () {
  if (data.currentQuestion > 0) {
    data.currentQuestion -= 1;
    displayQuestion();
  }
}

function displayQuestion () {
  question.textContent = data.questions[data.currentQuestion].question;

  options.forEach(function (option, index) {
    let answer = data.questions[data.currentQuestion].answers[index];
    // set the value of the radio button
    option.value = answer;
    // set the text of the label next to it
    option.nextElementSibling.textContent = answer;
    // reset the selected value
    option.checked = false
  });
}

function evaluate () {
  let correctAnswer = data.questions[data.currentQuestion].correctAnswer;
  // get the value of the currently selected answer
  let selectedAnswer = document.querySelector('#options :checked');

  if(selectedAnswer && selectedAnswer.value == correctAnswer){
    nextQuestion();
  }
}

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', evaluate);
backBtn.addEventListener('click', prevQuestion);
displayQuestion();
```

```css
  fieldset {
    border: none;
  }

  /* highlight the label immediately after the selected radio button */
  #options input:checked + label {
    border: 3px red solid;
  }

  /* hide the actual radio button 
     that the labels are controling. */
  #options input {
    display: none;
  }

  /* make the label look like a button */
  #options label {
    padding: .5em;
    background: #eee;
    border: outset 1px #eee;
  }
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <h2 id="question"></h2>
  <fieldset id="options">
    <input id="answer1" type="radio" name="answers"> <label for="answer1"></label>
    <input id="answer2" type="radio" name="answers"> <label for="answer2"></label>
    <input id="answer3" type="radio" name="answers"> <label for="answer3"></label>
    <input id="answer4" type="radio" name="answers"> <label for="answer4"></label>
  </fieldset>

  <button id="submit" type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
  <button id="back" type="button" name="button">Back</button>
</div>
```